# Android consequential animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to create next animation for a game:
firstly image is zooming out from normal size almost to zero,
than changing current image onto "flash" bitmap (bitm).
than performing second animation with new bitmap (bitm).
Currently I can use these two animations separately,
but can not use them consequentially.
how to wait until first animation is finished and only then change the bitmap and perform second animation?
Or is there another better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    ImageView im;
    Button btnStart;
    Bitmap bitm;
    Animation zoomOut, flash;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stopwatch);
        //flash bitmap 
        bitm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flash);

        // loading the animation
        zoomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.zoom_out);
        flash =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.flash);

        // setting animation listeners
        zoomOut.setAnimationListener(this);
        flash.setAnimationListener(this);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                im.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // TODO: How to wait until this animation is finished ???
                im.startAnimation(zoomOut);
                // and only then change bitmap and perform second animation??
                im.setImageBitmap(bitm);
                im.startAnimation(flash);

            }
        });
    }
```

here are my animations:
Zoom out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.1"
        android:toYScale="0.1" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

flash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="700"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little odd that your class is implementing AnimationListener and you are setting both animations to use it; maybe you are doing something else there... I recommend adding separate listeners to each one. Then in onAnimationEnd, add the bitmap change and start the next animation there, that way it will wait until the 1st animation is over.

```
zoomOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //put the code to do the bitmap change
        //start the next animation here
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a solution!